# Is server side error handling necessary for Angular app if Angular app is properly validating the client form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

For example, I have HTML like this:

```
<form novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="name" required />
    <button type="submit" ng-submit="saveThis()"> Save </button>
</form>
```

I am handling the error `required` using Angular.

Now on server post method:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    req.checkBody('name', 'name is required.').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors) {
        //Send these errors to angular
    } else {
        //Code for saving data
    }
}
```

My question is:

I am already handling the error in Angular. Then what is the need for having server-side validations?

If you say that if Javascript is disabled in the browser, then I need server-side errors. But then my form will never be posted as I am using `ng-submit` from Angular to post the data because Angular will also not work if Javascript is disabled.

Ok, you may say that if my server gets a request from another app, then I think its necessary. If you know any other exceptions then please let me know. But let's come back to my app's scope:

If it is necessary to send server errors to my Angular app, then can you help me to send the error messages from the server to Angular and then display them on HTML page?

**Update: code requested by @paqash**

In my controller:

```
$scope.submit = function(effect) {

    effectService.save(effect, function(err, result, status) {

        $scope.effect = null;
        if(!(effect == null || effect == undefined)) {
            if(!(effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '')) {
                $scope.currentEffectName = null;                         
                $location.path('/effect');
            }
        }

        $setPristine();
        $setUntouched();

    });
}
```

And in my service:

```
function save(effect, callback) {
    if(effect == undefined || effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '') {
        $http.post('/api/effect', effect);
    } else {
        $http.put('/api/effect/' + effect._id, effect);
    }
}
```

**Update2:**

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <ul class="errors" ng-if="errors.length > 0">
        <li class="alert alert-danger" ng-repeat="error in errors"> {{error.msg}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is controller save function:

```
$scope.submit = function(effect) {

    effectService.save(effect, function(err, result, status) {

        if(err) {
            $scope.errors = err;
        }
        else {
            $scope.errors = null;
        }

         ...........

    });

}
```

And here is the service:

```
function save(effect, callback) {
    if(effect == undefined || effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '') {
        $http.post('/api/effect', effect).then(saveSuccessCallback, saveFailureCallback);
    } else {
        $http.put('/api/effect/' + effect._id, effect).then(saveSuccessCallback, saveFailureCallback);
    }
}

function saveSuccessCallback() {
    //Clear errors
    return true;
}

function saveFailureCallback() {
    //Raise errors
    return false;
}
```

I have removed all the client-side validations for checking server-side validations. Now, when I click on Save button without entering anything in the input box, I don't see any errors.

Comment: Depends on your design. In a nicely separated application your front-end might call a service so you can share your service call between different consuming applications. In that case you should enforce business logic in at least server side to ensure no invalid request can be made. Also, Unit testing your server code will fail all business logic tests if you don't validate business logic server side

Comment: Maybe your data is validated on your site, but someone could send data to your service outside the browser and corrupt your data. In my opinion, always check data on server, and add client validation to avoid unnecessary call to your server.

Comment: In addition, in general, I let the UI worry about input validation and add any business rules as needed, i.e:  you can't select A if you selected B etc.. when then making the call to server side, I make sure the server code can stand on it's own, ensuring all business logic for the given operation is validated. Yes, you can throw violations (Business logic specific errors) and return the violation codes to the front-end, who can use a look-up to obtain the message to display for example.

Comment: @Fran Thank you for good suggestion. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @PortePoisse In a few words you explained me the whole concept. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server side validation is necessary, yes. You can never trust the client.

You can send those errors with:

```
res.status(400).send({errors: errors});
```

And then in your `saveThis` method you check for the http code of the response and if there are errors, you display them.

Edit: your $http methods can be chained with a success and error callback, like this:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Once you add the errorCallback method, it will fire when your status isn't 200-something and you can check the status of the response object there and the data for errors.

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post).

**Update by @vishal (op):**

Here is how I passed the response object from service:

```
function save(effect, callback) {
    if(effect == undefined || effect._id == undefined || effect._id == '') {
        $http.post('/api/effect', effect)
             .then(function (response) {
                 //Clear errors
                 callback(response);
             }, function(response) {
                 //Raise errors
                 callback(response);
             });
    } else {
        ............
    }
}
```

And then in controller:

```
$scope.submit = function(effect) {

    effectService.save(effect, function(response) {

        console.log(response);

        if(response.status == 400) {
            $scope.errors = response.data.errors;
        }
        else {
            $scope.errors = null;
        }

        ...........

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Can you please give an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: An example of checking for the http code of the response.

Comment: I have updated my question with the requested code. Can you please check the update part in question?

Comment: I have tried to use success and error callbacks as you suggested. But still I am not getting any error messages. Can you please take a look at update2 part of question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137477/discussion-between-paqash-and-vishal).

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I edited your answer for others reference.

Answer (score 4):

*Never implicitly trust anything you get from the client.*

It's important, so I'm going to repeat it...

*Never implicitly trust anything you get from the client.*

---

Okay, now that that's out of the way... The answer to this question is really *up to you*.  Ask yourself:

> Is it a bad thing if my server-side code operates on unvalidated form data?

If it's bad, then your server-side code needs to protect itself from that eventuality.  Maybe it's rare that it will happen, maybe it will *never* happen.  Consider yourself lucky if that's the case.  But it *can* happen, so write code to handle that situation.

If it's not bad, if the system can continue just fine and there's really nothing that can go wrong if someone submits unvalidated data, then you probably don't need to validate it.

Basically, you're blending together two very different questions.  One is:

> Should I bother with server-side validation as a general practice?

To which the answer is a resounding **yes**.  The other is:

> In my particular case, is it really necessary?

And the answer to that is really up to you and the logic/needs/etc. of the system you're building.  There are certainly cases where the "validation" is entirely for the purpose of improving the user experience and nothing can really "go wrong" when it's not done.  (For example, a user submitting an empty form might just create an empty record.  Structurally valid, just useless.  The user now successfully has an empty record, no big deal.)  Whether or not this is such a case is up to you.

Comment: Thank you @david. I will keep that in mind and whenever I am confused, I will look at this answer. For now I have decided to have validations on server as well. So, I will upvote your answer and move to next one. Thanks again.